# Sample balancing with batting averages

Tags: sampling

I'm trying to compare regional batting averages year over year (using comparable time periods i.e. August of each year) but I'm running into what I think is a sample imbalance.  This is an extreme example, but say hypothetically a player goes 10-for-10 one day (double-header) and on the same relative day the next year, he goes 1-for-1.

In both cases, his batting average for that day is 1.000.  However, he obviously did much better the first day, but from an average perspective, there is no difference.

Because of the regional data and time period assumptions I need to use, I will sometimes have 25 observations one day and 1 observation the same relative day the next year.

I ran a Wilcoxin-Mann-Whitney test on the monthly samples comparing the two years (since the daily data seems to be too small) and they generally show no difference in the medians, but I'm looking for some opinions on if/how to balance the data by at-bats, rather then going strictly off of the batting average.

Because of the collection method, I only have samples and at this point I am unable to gather additional data.

Comment: Instead of averaging over daily batting averages why not calculate batting averages using the data from every day?  For example, if a player went 10-10 one day, then 1-1 the next day then 5-10 the next day then their batting average is 16/21 = 0.762 rather than (1.000+1.1000+0.500)/3 = 0.833?

Comment: That is the correct way to do it if you are calculating an average based on a group of consecutive days, but the goal of this project is to examine how groups of players performed year over year, given comparable time periods.  So for example, this group of 5 players had 24 at bats on the third Tuesday of June in year one but only 5 at bats on the third Tuesday of June in year 2.  The batting average may be the same but the sample sizes are different, and I am wondering how to tell if that difference is statistically significant and if so, how to correct for it.